# I'm trying to open share point 2013 in mobile

Tags: sharepoint-2013

[share point mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2W1S.png)

I developed a site in share point 2013. its working good in desktop.

when im using share point in moblie. it showing Choose Switch to pc view.
but i need it to open directly. without choosing switch to pc view.

I mean site should open directly without choosing switch to pc view. can any one help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to site settings > Site Features and disable the mobile browser view feature...

Or using powershell:

```
disable-spfeature -identity MobilityRedirect -url http://addressofsite
```

Attention: the powershell option is a hidden setting which will prevent redirecting mobile users to the mobile view. I would prefer the first one, just deactivating the feature